# Input field with html tag - how to get it to not show the html tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an input field that shows the html tag and also does not do what it is supposed to do. In this case, show the content in 2 lines without the html tag. (like the display only does - shown next.)

[image]

After "My first edited comment" is entered by the User and before it is saved to the table I prepended it with the 'name of the user' surrounded with the p tag. I did this so when it is subsequently shown either for update via an input tag or display via a div tag that the "My first edited comment" goes to a 2nd line. It works for display but not for edit in an input tag.

The data in the database table that is in the model that is used.

```
 <p>reguser1</p>My first edited comment.
```

I have a display only field that does NOT show the html tag and does what the tag is supposed to do.

[image]

The data in the database table that is in the model that is used.

```
<p>reguser2</p>My first comment about this new blog site.
```

---

How do I code the input field to display properly - the "My first edited comment" goes to a 2nd line?

I'm using what I use for the display only field to decode the HTML - using decode to get rid of the tags.

```
value="@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))"
```

I tried this as well - but get an error:

```
 <div class="form-control" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "inputEditComment", blogComment.BlogCommentId)" style="display: inline; margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))
 </div>
```

The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.'
```

---

Here is the asp.net partial view (not all of it):

```
                @if (blogComment.UserId == blogComment.SignedInUserId)
                {
                    @* Can edit the input field. *@
                    <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "inputEditComment", blogComment.BlogCommentId)" class="form-control" value="@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))" style="display: inline; margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;" />

                    <a href="" class="editComment" data-id="@blogComment.BlogCommentId">Save</a>
                    <a href="" class="deleteComment" data-id="@blogComment.BlogCommentId"> Delete</a>
                }
                else
                {
                    @* Display only. *@
                    <div style="margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;">
                        @Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))
                    </div>
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. You might be confused that inserting HTML inside input tag is not valid since it can only accept strings. And you are trying to insert HTML on your code here:

```
<input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "inputEditComment", blogComment.BlogCommentId)" class="form-control" value="@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))" style="display: inline; margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;" />
```

Which will not work, since it will still convert to string, that's why your output result is this:

[image]

If you really want to insert HTML, use HTML Editor, or perhaps, you can just put it inside the `div` like this one:

```
<div style="margin-top: 27px; font-size: 13px; color: #9c9898;">
   @Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(@blogComment.BlogCommentContent))
</div>
```

Comment: The picture in your reply should actually be the other one I posted.

Comment: I need it to be an input field. I thought that html decode would get rid of the tags.. I tried Html.EditorFor but get an error. I updated it above.

Comment: The user enters the content and then I enter a user name and prepend it with a p tag to the property before saving to the database. The idea being to have that entered content start on the 2nd line within the input tag.

Comment: I've taken a different design approach. No need to try and answer any longer.

Comment: I understand. Apologies if I wasn't able to get back to you the soonest time due to some errands.